# How to post and cast payload?

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, postman, httpclient

My goal is to call api (via post), accept payload as base type and later cast it to concrete type. If I do that from main solution (where my api stands), everything works well. But I can't understand why same code doesn't work from other solutions.

So I have my request (declared in different solutions)

```
namespace Nb
{
    public class NbRequestBase
    {
        public string BaseProp { get; set; }
    }
    public class NbRequestConcrete : NbRequestBase
    {
        public string ConcreteProp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("payments/nb")]
public IHttpActionResult Prepare(NbRequestBase request)
{
    if(request is NbRequestConcrete)
    {

    }

    try
    {
        // <<< INSERT CODE HERE >>>
        NbRequestConcrete nbRequestConcrete = (NbRequestConcrete)request;

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex);

        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

and this is my calling code:

```
    NbRequestConcrete requestTwo = new NbRequestConcrete()
    {
        BaseProp = "BaseProp",
        ConcreteProp = "ConcreteProp"
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var _clientId = "_clientId";
        var _clientSecret = "_clientSecret";

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50228");

        #region Formatter

        JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        formatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;

        List<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter>();
        formatters.Add(formatter);

        #endregion

        var responseMessage = client.PostAsync($"payments/nb?clientId={_clientId}&clientSecret={_clientSecret}", requestTwo, formatter).Result;
        responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

If I put my calling code into other project/solution (for example just new console app), API endpoint is hit, but payload is null.

[payload when called form console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Wxy.png)

If I put exacly same calling code into project where my api is (for example in same API endpoint method, at try/catch block start and call it again), API endpoint is hit, payload is NOT null and casting works. Why is it? And how to fix it?

[payload when called from same solution try/catch start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZeK1.png)

And BTW. How to make this call via postman?

Regards

Comment: `request` is null or `nbConcreteRequest` is null?

Comment: I updated my question. Payload images added

Answer (score 0):

This line tells the model binder to set the values of any matching properties in `request` to the value that was passed to the API:

```
public IHttpActionResult Prepare(NbRequestBase request)
```

The model binder does not attach all the other properties to the request, because it has no idea what they would be.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Assemblies name where NbRequestConcrete in console app lived in one assembly and on API lived in other. So request was different.

```
{
  "$type": "Nb.NbRequestConcrete, Tester",
  "ConcreteProp": "ConcreteProp",
  "BaseProp": "BaseProp"
}
```

VS

```
{
  "$type": "Nb.NbRequestConcrete, MYApi",
  "ConcreteProp": "ConcreteProp",
  "BaseProp": "BaseProp"
}
```